# Derby+apache can't find main

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I've downloaded db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin installed it according to [this guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_download) Now when I try to run code below it says: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/impl/tools/sysinfo/Main
(I've installed it into orp/Apache/derby)

```
public class Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("POOP");
        new Sample2().go(args);
        System.out.println("SimpleApp finished");


    }
    void go(String[] args){
        Connection conn = null;
        ArrayList statements = new ArrayList(); 
        PreparedStatement psInsert = null;
        PreparedStatement psUpdate = null;
        Statement s = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String dbName = "Lab4DB";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName);
            System.out.println("Connected to and created database " + dbName);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private String framework = "embedded";
    private String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    private String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
}
```

My main class is in my workspace directory. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

derby.jar and derbytools.jar must be present in CLASSPATH in order to use apache derby.

Comment: my $CLASSPATH: 
/opt/Apache/db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin/lib/derby.jar:/opt/Apache/db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin/lib/derbytools.jar:
it doesn't work though